# Cannot access the Jtable column data after set invisible

Tags: java, jtable

After setting a JTable column to invisible, i cannot get reference to the component.

```
Component cellEditor;
String name;
String value;
// loop row then column
for(int j=0 ; j<tolCol ; j++){
    /* get cell name in JTable */
    System.out.println(j + " " + ((JTable)comp).getModel().getValueAt(0, j));
    tce = ((JTable)comp).getCellEditor(0, j); // <-- ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
}
```

When i use System.out.println(j + " " + ((JTable)comp).getModel().getValueAt(0, j)); i manage to print all the value out. Is there anything else i need to do to get the reference of component?

Answer (score 1):

> After setting a JTable column to
>   invisible

If you have **removed** the column in order to make it **invisible**, then you will get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. But you can access `((JTable)comp).getModel().getValueAt(0, j)`

Comment: Exactly, i have removed the column to make it invisible. 

I need to get the component of that cell, because there are quite some information in there. Getting just the value at it is not enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need the cell editor of a hidden column. It sounds like a bad design.

Even your code to access the data is not corrent because the model and the view can be different. The order of the columns in the model never change. Lets assume your table model can contain the following data in 3 columns: "String", "Integer", "Date". Now lets assume the user reorders the table by dragging the "Date" columns to the first column of the table.

Now when you access table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0) you will get a "String" value.

When you access table.getCellEditor(row, 0) you will get the editor for a "Date" object.

To access the default editor for a given Class type you can do:

```
Class clazz = table.getModel().getColumnClass(0);
TableCellEditor tce = table.getDefaultEditor( clazz );
```

Comment: No need to worry in that sense because the column is not movable.
Currently i am using the setcolumn size to 0 as a temporary solution. 

i still cannot access the component by using the sample you provided above.

Comment: The component doesn't have any additional information. When you invoke the editor all it does it take the data from the model and display it in the editor, so I still don't understand what you are attempting to do.