# What is the best Java GUI methodology for ease of maintenance and enhancement?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I need advice on how to rewrite a java GUI. Ultimate goal is easier to maintain & enhance.

What I have built is a Java Applet Client interface that acts and behave similar to Eclipse. developer can design their data entry forms without using a single line of code (drag and drop), and define its attribute.  This part is pretty well iron out. however, i am left with more than 40,000 lines of codes that is very difficult to maintain.

Each time a bug is occur or a new enhancement, i normally cant program in a more direct way. more than half the time, i need to workaround the problem and that adds up the lines of code.

Consideration:

-Java Web Applet (because it runs on any browser with J2RE installed)

-runs on slow machine

-deployment of around 200 nodes and growing

Problems that i currently have:

-Listeners are all over the place. sometimes is inside the element.AddListener(new listener..). Sometimes is outside of the class, could be in another package that contain all the rest of listener.
Question: is it always good idea to put all listener in another package? if that is that case, i cant use "this." to get the reference i need.

-JTable this is a killer to me :(  the problem i had on [Cannot access the Jtable column data after set invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264119/cannot-access-the-jtable-column-data-after-set-invisible) still persist. Imagine i have JTable with 3 column. First column is a dropDown, second and third column is a textfield. Whenever a value choose from dropdown, i need to base on the selected value, and update to the second column and third column. the problem is, if the user click and it click on other row very fast, it will update to a column that is in the wrong row.

-Currently the program is coded in the sense of it is single thread. whenever the user does a http connection to the server side, reading a file, writing a file and etc, i need to make it as asynchronous process so it doenst feel like "program hang". what is the best way to do this?

Really appreciate help here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of questions here and I'm not sure where to start but I can sympathize with you one this one.  Unless you have a well seasoned team that has already gone through the pains of Swing application development things can quickly become out of control and unmanageable.

Before you adventure into re-writing a project I would start with defining some simple standards for development.  Like package structures and listeners.  I would also recommend splitting the application up into well **unit tested** modules or sub projects.

Also, ask yourself if you really need to re-write the application or does it just need some TLC.  As a consultant and Director of IT I see developers always wanting to re-write applications just because they've learned something new or don't think it's up to par.  When they come to me and tell me that it's junk and needs to be re-written I usually send them back and ask them to come up with alternative solutions to a re-write and the impact of each solution including - doing nothing.  In a lot of cases we didn't write the application at all.

[UPDATE]
Lastly, If you are going to re-write I would use a [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) and [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach.  **Yes, I said MVC for desktop applications!**.  We've had great success with these methodologies.  It keeps a good separation of concern and makes things easily re-usable.  It also provides the structure to easily switch out the presentation layer.  Most importantly it's easy to unit test and any developer that understands MVC can understand the basics of your project without knowing the details.

I have some more thoughts but i'll leave it at that for now.  ;)

Comment: I have to agree with you that currently i am facing alot of issue in this Swing application. it is difficult to control and lines of codes shoot up the skies the moment i realize it. i would like to keep all the listeners and bean because that is where the business logic is. what do you think is best? i would love not to rewrite the whole lot. if you could share some experience will be best! thanks!

Comment: Added an update to my answer.  An MVC approach rocks for organizing and structuring a Swing application!

Comment: Sounds promising. thanks michael! i am soaking myself on how best to restructure current application to 100% MVC compliance. would you help to clarify this, according to wiki: "Swing, which uses a Model-Delegator pattern, where the view and controller are combined, but the model is separate". is this true and should?

Comment: Some suggest "MVC in SWING is really MV/C". is it correct? base on "http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=11199"

Comment: Yes i would agree that MVC in Swing is really MV/C and the model is tightly integrated within the view.  This allows you to focus on the views, controllers and domain which really drive progress.  I also like to layout my projects similar to Ruby on Rails and/or Groovy on Grails projects but include the domain in a separate project.

Answer (score 0):

use dsl for gui:

- swinghtmltemplate
- swixml
- yaml

there are some more of them

this will remove the need to describe listeners, allow binding in dsl manner

Comment: Err.... these 3 are alien to me. what are they? i did a quick google, but it doesnt make sense when comes to developing Java GUI

Comment: I doubt these will help cleaning up existing Swing code. Obviously the problem is not with the "views" but rather with the "controllers" (listeners and actions).

Comment: this will help you to make total separation between gui markup and controller listeers. 

http://code.google.com/p/swinghtmltemplate/ see the example here. 
You get the whole form markup in separate place with no panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER) etc
Also you can attach listeners with dsl, not in code (forget button.addActionListener(...))

Comment: With Swinghtmltemplate, it seems not just java codes, there are maven, html (i dont really likes tag) and css. That will result in more codes to be maintain :( . This is not something i like to do.

Comment: @PenkovVladimir yaml is a language for structured data (similar to XML), so it could be used to store a GUI specification (like HTML does for your swinghtmltemplate code) but it is not doing the translation to a Swing layout. Did you mean to mention something yaml-based in the list?

Comment: @toolforger 10 years comment. I meant - just describe UI in any language suitable for describing structured data and create some converter.





UPD in 2021 just don't use swing, if you can.

Comment: Well, Swing is still very much alive in the product I'm maintaining :-)

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just reuse the eclipse framework to build your own gui instead of writing it from scratch in Swing ?

Comment: In Production, i have more than 200 nodes to take care. 
Deployment and able to run on Slower machine is top priority on choosing platform. i should have highlight this easlier. thanks.

Comment: Eclipse framework means going from Swing to SWX. Can you explain how SWX would help?